# Filter data from multiple tables

Tags: filter, merge, key, powerbi

I work on `Power BI` and I want to create a Slicer (Filter) to multiple tables that have a common key (like in excel that I can choose a slicer and the pivot tables that it will affect on).

Is there any way to do so or do I have to I merge the tables I want to work on?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a relationship between the tables: `Home` tab -> `Manage Relationships` -> `New` / `Autodetect`.

Make sure to set Cross Filter Direction to `both`.

There is no many-many relationship model, so if the column has duplicate values in both tables, you will need to introduce a third table with unique values to join on.